# Как при клике показать другую половину div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день! Как сделать, что при начальном состоянии показывалось 50% этого div, а после нажатия на кнопку показывалась другие 50%?

```
<script>
 function change(idName) {
 if(document.getElementById(idName).style.display=='none') {
 document.getElementById(idName).style.display = '';
 } else {
 document.getElementById(idName).style.display = 'none';
 }
 return false;
 }
 </script>

<div style="display:none;" id="test">
<div class="hide">
 Подкатегории: 
 <a href="#"> Белые комоды</a>  
 <a href="#"> Большие</a>  
 <a href="#"> В гостиную</a>  
</div>
 </div>
<a href="#" onclick="change('test')">Ещё</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если допускается использование jquery, то можно так:

```js
$(function(){
  var h=$(".hide").height(); //получаем высоту блока с контентом
  $(".hide").css({"height": h/2}); //устанавливаем высоту блока с контентом в 50%
  
  $(".button").click(function(){ //нажатие на кнопку
    if(h==$(".hide").height()){ //если высота блока на момент нажатия на кнопку равно изначальной высоте блока то
      $(".hide").css({"height": h/2}); //устанавливаем высоту блока в 50% от изначальной
    }
    else {  //иначе
      $(".hide").css({"height": h}); //устанавливаем высоту блока в 100%
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
<div class="hide">
 Подкатегории: <br/>
 <a href="#"> Белые комоды</a><br/>  
 <a href="#"> Большие</a>  <br/>
 <a href="#"> В гостиную</a>  <br/>
</div>
<button class="button">Ещё</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
  var el = document.querySelector(".hide");

  if(el.style.height === 'auto') {
    el.style.height = '0';
    this.innerText = 'Еще';
  } else {
    el.style.height = 'auto';
    this.innerText = 'Скрыть';
  }                                         
}, false);
```

```css
a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hide {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  Подкатегории: 
  <a href="#"> Белые комоды</a>  
  <a href="#"> Большие</a>  
  <a href="#"> В гостиную</a>  

  <div class="hide">
    <a href="#"> В гостиную</a>  
    <a href="#"> Белые комоды</a>  
    <a href="#"> Большие</a>  
    <a href="#"> В гостиную</a>  
    <a href="#"> Белые комоды</a>  
    <a href="#"> Большие</a>  
    <a href="#"> В гостиную</a>  
    <a href="#"> Белые комоды</a>  
    <a href="#"> Большие</a>  
    <a href="#"> В гостиную</a>  
  </div>
</div>

<button>Ещё</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так -

```js
let toggleButton = document.querySelector('.slider-toggle');
let slider = document.querySelector('.slider');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', toggleButton_clickHandler);

function toggleButton_clickHandler() {
  toggleButton.classList.add('hide-toggle-button');
  slider.classList.add('hide-slider');
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.left,
.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.left {
  background: tomato;
}
.right {
  background: gold;
}
.slider {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transition: left 1s;
}
.slider-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  background: #232323;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: left 1s, opacity 1s;
}
.slider-toggle:hover {} .hide-toggle-button {
  left: 40%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.hide-slider {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider-toggle">
  <span>next</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Что нибудь вроде:

```
   <style>
    .test{
     overflow: hidden;
     background: lightgrey;
    }

    .wrapper{
      min-width:300px;
    }      

    .test.hide{
     width: 150px;
    }

    .test.show{
     min-width: 300px;
    }
   </style>

    <script>
     function change(idName) {
     var elem = document.getElementById(idName);
     if(elem.hasClass(hide)) {
       elem.addClass(show);
       elem.removeClass(hide);
     } else {
       elem.addClass(hide);
       elem.removeClass(show);
     }
     return false;
     }
    </script>

       <div style="display:none;" id="test" class="test show">
         <div class="wrapper">
         Подкатегории: 
         <a href="#"> Белые комоды</a>  
         <a href="#"> Большие</a>  
         <a href="#"> В гостиную</a>  
         </div>
       </div>

       <a href="#" onclick="change('test')">Ещё</a>
```

Comment: я думаю автору нужно не в ширину скрывать текст, а в высоту - чтоб кнопкой "Еще" показывать длинный список

Comment: Думаю, поставить стили для изменения по высоте - не так сложно будет)

Comment: а если списки динамические и их много? :)

Comment: Тогда, думаю, стоит поставить скролл внутрь этого меню `overflow-y: auto;`, ведь их там может быть очень много и больше какой-нибудь высоты даже их половина перестанет влезать в экран) Тут уж от дизайна надо отталкиваться.